# How do I install the Glide Wrapper on Diablo 2 with PlayOnLinux?

Tags: diablo-ii, ubuntu

I just installed Diablo 2 via PlayOnLinux in my Netbook and now I would like to know how to make the Glide Wrapper work. I also install 1.14d patch so I can play on BattleNet, but this patch disabled the option for the game to automatically select the Glide wrapper. I know that in Windows there's is a runaround for this which is to add the parameter `-3dfx` in the properties of the D2 shortcut, but I don't know how to do this in PlayOnLinux nor do I know if it's the correct way.

So please can somebody tell me what to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how specifically this applies to Diablo or your patch, but as for adding parameters, two ways come to mind:

1)

1. Click "Configure" in the upper right.
2. Select the appropriate shortcut from the list on the left of the window that appears.
3. Put `-3dfx` in the "arguments" box on the "General" tab.

2)

1. Click "Configure" in the upper right.
2. Go to the "Miscellaneous" tab.
3. "Open a Shell"
4. Find and launch your executable adding your arguments as desired.

The second method is the one I personally seem to have more success with, but it is a bit harder to initially nail down how exactly to launch your executable.